Curve factor at position
We can get the position at a curve factor (or length) using Sample Curve node. Is there a way to get the factor from the position?
Edit: More specifically I am looking to find the factor of control point of the curve meeting certain criteria like "having the smallest x position (the left most point)", So the position will always be on the curve.
Edit2: The node setup below is my first - rather naive attempt at finding the position. I am just selecting the point that has smallest x value (found by attribute statistics), instantiating a dummy object to get the position from selection (I could not find a node which uses selection to get the position, so had to use instance on points).
As seen in the screenshot the sphere does move to the correct position and since it's the only instance,I guess the value at the socket marked in yellow will be the position I am looking for. This only gives position and not the index.

Next I tried the approach suggest by @StefLAncien as shown below where the x value is used as weight of Points of Curve node and then we get the actual position at this index using Sample index. But as you can see the sphere doesn't move to the position. Also tried Spline domain instead of Point. Maybe I am missing something. If we get this index, as suggested by @Gordon Brinkmann, we can get the factor using spline parameter.



I do not know such a node. I am actually using a "Points of Curve" node with the weight equal to the "Distance" between the "Position" and the coordinates I am targeting to recover the closest control point. Then a "Spline Parameter" node to get this control point factor, and to do a linear interpolation of the "Factor" with the next CP. A more sophisticated approach is to do a dichotomy with a "Repeat Zone". A brut force approach is to oversample the curve, convert it to a point cloud capturing the "Factor", then to find the nearest point. It all depends on the accuracy you are looking for.

You want to get the factor from position vectors (XYZ coordinates which happen to be somewhere on the curve), or specific positions given by control points of the curve?

@GordonBrinkmann Specific position given by control points of the curve. More specifically factor of control point meeting certain criteria like "having the smallest x position (the left most point)", So the position will always be on the curve. (Have updated the question)

As an example, for the smallest x position of all the control points, you can use a "Points of Curve" node with the weight set to x. The first returned index will be associated with the smallest x.

@StefLAncien Thanks that's a very useful pointer. I got to the point of finding the position of the point somehow - your suggestion is far better - but stuck at getting the factor.

@StefLAncien Isn't the Sample Index node exactly made for something like this? Read a value that you can plug in from somewhere (like the Spline Parameter node) at a certain index (like the index of a control point)?

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

Dark pink nodes:
The index of the control point with the smallest X coordinate is a property of each Spline making the Curve, not of each control point. Consequently, it is sampled in the Spline domain. As there is only one Spline in the demonstration case, the Index parameter of the Sample Index node is set to 0.
To get the index of the control point of interest, the X coordinate of each control point is input as the Weights parameter of a Points of Curve node. Because the smallest X coordinate is expected, the Sort Index parameter is set to 0, yielding the index of the first point after sorting. It is to notice that the Curve Index socket is left unconnected. Consequently, this value is provided by the Sample Index node (i.e. 0 here, i.e. the first and only Spline).
Dark green nodes:
The Factor of the control point of interest is recovered by a second Sample Index node set in the Point domain. Its value is provided by a Spline Parameter node.
Dark blue nodes:
To check this Factor, a Sample Curve node is used to recover the Position of the control point of interest. This position is offsetting the vertices of an UV Sphere (beware to plug the Offset socket and not the Position socket, otherwise all the UV Sphere vertices are collapsing at the same location).

The following figure shows in light grey background the nodes to add to deal with more than one Spline in the Curve :

Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Yes, this works! Could you please explain why we need to get index from point index? Are these 2 (point index and index) different? Using point index to get the factor from a single Sample Index node (connecting Points of Curve output directly to second Sample index's index socket and using Spline Parameters factor as value) doesn't seem to work.

So if I basically understood everything correct, you want the factor where a certain control point sits. If you can determine the conrol point (and your comment under the question sounded like you can do that), you have its index. Then it's quite easy to get the factor of the spline where the control point is.
There is a Sample Index node where you can sample data at a given index. So for example if have curve with control points and each control point has an index, then I can plug an Index node into the Sample into the Sample Index node, and the value I want to sample is the Spline Factor.
Then I store it as a named attribute "cp_factor" so every control point has an attribute with the spline factor of its current position.
Here is a simple example with a straight line of 10 m length, so the X position is equal to the 10 times the factor so you can compare it easily (I also instanced icospheres to mark the positions, ignore the separate Index node, it works with the Index output of the Spline Parameter node as well):

Of course this does not only work because they are all equidistant apart, as randomizing the position of the positions show (but still a straight line since it is easier to see there):

So to get the value of a certain control point, you only need to read the attribute at the index of that point.
